# File redirection in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, redirection

What's the difference between using > and >>?

How can I use both < and > (redirection operators) in a single command?

Comment: Please can you break this into separate questions.

Comment: Smells like homework....

Comment: Nah, I was just reading 'Learning the shell' and I was just wondering about a few things.

I'm assuming `` is command redirection, {} is for lists,  and "" is to help bash understand the command. 

I'm a little confused on the whole echo thing though. I'm assuming I'd just say FIRST=`name` etc and then just echo Last, middle, ssn etc

I just want a better understanding.

Comment: I suggest you follow Diago's advice. This site works best when there is **a** single question that can be answered. So go ahead and ask four different questions, it's not like we charge extra...

Answer (score 2):

`>` redirects data from `stdout` (read standard out) to a file.

> ls -a > my-files.txt

will take the output of `ls -a` and put it into a file named `my-files.txt` deleting/overwriting the file if it exists. Using `>>` instead of `>` in the example above will not overwrite the file if it exists but add the output of `ls -a` to the end of `my-files.txt`

`<` on the other hand sends data to a programs `stdin` (read standard in).
If I have a file called `my-files.txt`and I want to know how many words it contains I can send it to a program called `wc`. This program accepts data on it's `stdin` so to the data to it I do

> wc -w < my-files.txt

And lastly If I want to save the output of that command to a new file I can use both like so

> wc -w < my-files.txt > wordcount.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try,
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)
An in-depth exploration of the art of shell scripting

1. [Special Characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html), [Quoting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html)
2. [IO Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
3. [Introduction to Variables and Parameters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

`>>` means just *append / create if not exists*, very useful for logs.

`<<` also exists and useful. Try:

```
$ cat > a <<EOF
some text here
more text
EOF

$ cat a
```

You see that file `a` contains text between two `EOF`.